# How to fetch data from database into google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

When I try to fetch data from database into google sheet it show the following error failed to establish database connection check connection string, username and password(line no 9) can anyone kindly help me to resolve this problems.My code is this 
    function myMySQLFetchData() {

```
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/attendance_system', 'root', '');

  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var start = new Date();

  var rs = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM employee GROUP BY 1 LIMIT 1000'); 

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var row = 0;
  var getCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < getCount; i++){  
     cell.offset(row, i).setValue(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1)); 
  }  `enter code here`

  var row = 1; 
  while (rs.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) { 
      cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1)); 
    }
    row++;
  }

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime())); 
}
```

[click here to view image in the image the error has mention in red color][1]
     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN95K.png

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And the code shown in the image is a variant of JavaScript, a language unrelated to any you have tagged. Don't spam tags, especially completely unrelated tags.

Answer (score 1):

The code in a .gs file is run server side on Google's servers.  You are using an internal IP in your url so the server is not going to find the database.  You will need an external path to the database.

Also, you are showing no password being passed.  I don't want to assume you have just removed this, but expect that to be the case.  So I am only mentioning this on the off chance you are not passing a password as well.